# On Google Data Studio, using PostgreSQL data, how do I "SELECT * ..." but for camelCase columns?

Tags: postgresql, looker-studio, quoted-identifier

On Google Data Studio, I cannot create a chart from Postgres data if table columns are in camelCase. I have data in PostgreSQL where I want to get charts from. Integrating it as a data source works fine. Now, I have a problem when creating a chart.

After creating a chart and selecting a data source, I try to add a column, which results in this error:

```
Error with SQL statement: ERROR: column "columnname" does not exist Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "table.columnName". Position: 8
```

It just so happens that all my columns are in camelCase. Is there no way around this? Surely this is a basic question that has been resolved.

Comment: Another good example why using camelCase is [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive)

Comment: @Scoots Unfortunately, no. I am in a position where I cannot change the column names of the data. In Google Data Studio I'm unable to "query" the data directly i.e. `SELECT table."columnName" FROM table;`, instead what GDS seems to be doing is `SELECT table.columnname FROM table;`

Comment: @wtwtwt Ahh I see. I've looked around but I've only been able to find people reporting the same issue, no one offering a solution that does not involve refactoring the table to not have uppercase characters.

Comment: @Scoots do you think it is possible to create an alias for all columns using camelCase? I was reading into creating `VIEWS` on PostgreSQL

Answer (score 3):

When connecting to your data source, try using 'Custom query' instead of selecting a table from your database. Then manually write your SQL query where you cast your camel case column names to lower case using sql alias. Worked for me.

example:

```sql
SELECT
  "camelCaseColA" as cola,
  "camelCaseColB" as colb,
  "camelCaseColC" as colc
FROM
  tableName as table
```

Comment: So Google Data Studio basically doesnt work properly with case sensitive postgresql databases? Its a bug then, because postgres support case sensitive columns, so there is no reason not to suport it.